# Observer/Dealloc errors and crash with unseen UIViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController which has objects perform a series of tasks on background threads as it appears, and it's registered as an observer to them. When they get called for the first time, it stops being an observer.

I realised I could save user time if these tasks were performed before the view controller is shown, so I initialized it and called a method which ran these tasks.

Then I started getting errors along the lines of:

```
An instance [insance] of class [class name] was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it.
```

How can I prevent this from happening? If i show the view controller straight away, this works no problem.

Comment: What is retaining the view controller if you don't show it?

Comment: It's a property of my class, I assume that's enough to retain it. How else could I retain it? EDIT: Oh, i was convinced it is, turns out it isn't. I presume making it so will retain it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend, that you add a call [notificationCenter removeObserver: self] in method dealloc of those classes, which you intend to use as observers, as it is the last chance to unregister an observer cleanly.